# Images not loading in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

I am working on a wordpress site. My theme is Newspaper theme - themeforest. My issue is when I load my site, images are not shown. But when I reload, images appear. What can be the possible issue. Site is https://ashknows.com/

Comment: I can see all images on Home page, on first load itself. Can you tell where to check ?

Comment: @SudharshanNair There are four blogs and only two of them have images at first load.Same in "Don't Miss", "What's new" and "Latest post"

Comment: Actually Images are loading, Jut when we resize screen images are showing which are not shown

Comment: but all images have same size. Also,why do they appear after reloading page?

Comment: @SudharshanNair i guess re-sizing calls reload mechanism, As if i load the site on an already re-sized tab, bottom images are not loaded

Comment: I mean once page is loaded, Just try to resize browser, all images are loaded perfectly.Some sort of issue with JS

Comment: ok, I'll look into js